# Stick, scion or twig

Tags: word-choice, image-identification

[image]

What do we call the thing [slid in eyes to apply khol] lying with the kohl bottle in the picture?

> Stick
>
> Twig
>
> scion

Answer (score 3):

It's simply called a "kohl applicator".

> Applying kohl on the waterline involves dipping **a rod-like applicator** into kohl powder and then, after flicking off the excess, passing the rod through the base of the lashes while the eyes are closed. If done correctly, the wet conjunctiva picks up the powder from the side of **the rod** creating a smooth, even line.
>
> [Cosmetics and Skin.com](https://www.cosmeticsandskin.com/cdc/kohl.php)

Since it has no specific name, you can call it any of the words you mentioned. Although twig and scion can be taken as something much thinner. I'd prefer "**rod**" or "**stick**".

As mentioned by @xeesid in the comments, "**kohl needle**" could be used too.

Comment: I think saying "stick" is better than ["rod" = "pole"](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1309&bih=692&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=FdBfXd2iC4uxkwWR7rgY&q=rod+pole&oq=rod+pole&gs_l=img.3..0l2j0i5i30l3j0i8i30l5.17295.22171..23012...0.0..0.86.429.6......0....1..gws-wiz-img.TnM8d23k7M0&ved=0ahUKEwidgd3m85jkAhWL2KQKHRE3DgMQ4dUDCAY&uact=5)

Comment: Note that the sites that use the term ["rod" for eye makeup](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1309&bih=692&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=edBfXb_rC4jasAfkw7WgDg&q=rod+eye+makeup&oq=rod+eye+makeup&gs_l=img.3...12389.21764..22261...0.0..0.238.1142.13j0j1......0....1..gws-wiz-img.......0i67j0j0i5i30.wKC-XMBRYOg&ved=0ahUKEwj_i7WW9JjkAhUILewKHeRhDeQQ4dUDCAY&uact=5) tools are, generally, Chinese. Aliexpress is a Chinese company.

Comment: @Mari-LouA When I read “stick” I think of makeup like lipstick or [foundation sticks](http://bpc.h-cdn.co/assets/17/21/1495819561-foundation-sticks.jpg). There’s even [stick deodorant](https://img.aws.livestrongcdn.com/ls-article-image-673/ds-photo/getty/article/176/175/147912535.jpg). “Applicator” would be my choice, but I did find a museum that used “kohl stick”: https://www.artic.edu/artworks/143561/kohl-stick while a search for “kohl rod” returned curtain rods, so stick is definitely better than rod.

Comment: What about Kohl needle?

Comment: @xeesid Yes, needle could be used too